# Unexpected "No such file or directory" in Python

Tags: python, file

My two line code for moving a file into the cwd is as follows:

```
import os, shutil
shutil.move(os.path.abspath('hello_file.txt'),os.getcwd())
```

I do have the file just one up the cwd but I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-333-f012757a9dca>", line 1, in <module>
    shutil.move(os.path.abspath('hello_file.txt'),os.getcwd())

  File "/Users/deepayanbhadra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 558, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)

  File "/Users/deepayanbhadra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)

  File "/Users/deepayanbhadra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/deepayanbhadra/Desktop/DIY-Python-Projects/Automating Tasks/hello_file.txt'
```

Comment: I mean, the error is pretty clear, no?

Comment: The file exists at this path: '/Users/deepayanbhadra/Desktop/DIY-Python-Projects/
Not the one in the error. Else, it'd have been pretty clear.

Comment: `abspath` doesn't mean "search my whole computer for a file with this name". It converts relative paths to absolute paths.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks for clarifying. This was my misconception.

Answer (score 0):

The file path you have provided is the current directory. You first have to change to the directory up. One of the ways you can do this is

```
import os 
os.chdir(“..”)
```

That’s the simplest way but will take you quite a number of lines of code to achieve the same